# I don't know how to parallelize my test in cucumber with @cucumberOption

Tags: cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I have this configuration:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
         features = "src/test/resources/features",
         glue = "com.cucumberTest.stepDefinitions",
         monochrome=true,
         plugin = {
                 "html:target/cucumber-html-report",
                 "json:target/cucumber.json",
                 "pretty:target/cucumber-pretty.txt",
                 "usage:target/cucumber-usage.json",
                 "junit:target/cucumber-results.xml"
                    }

)
```

and I try to convert in this:

```
Main.main(new String[]{"--threads", "4",
                "-p","timeline:target/cucumber-parallel-report",
               "-p","json:target/prueba/cucumber.json",
                "-p","junit:target/cucumber-results.xml",
                "-p","pretty:target/cucumber-pretty.txt",
               "-p","html:target/cucumber-html-report",
                "-g", "com.cucumberTest.stepDefinitions", "src/test/resources/features/"});
```

but with the tag @cucumberOption. Also I am trying use the next plugin for this and I think that I get it but I want to get in the @cucumberOptions

plugin:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <parallel>both</parallel>
                    <threadCount>15</threadCount>
                </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Can I get it?

Comment: I found this web https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm#list-configuration-options but the code response is 404

Comment: My solution was to use the next plugin <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId> and I got it following this tutorial http://grasshopper.tech/464/   I dont found a way for add to @cucumberOptions

Comment: still I dont get the final object because the plugin dont extract the job in threads in the same time. I am searching the soluction

Comment: how do u want to implement parallel execution, using junit or testng ? after i hear, would try to give you solution.

Comment: I am using Junit 4.12 with maven

Comment: I have tried to answer below, please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Key Point:** Before we start, would like to share a note for better understanding in future, we shall not mix direct & transitive dependencies specially their versions! Doing so can cause unpredictable outcome. Ok, let's understand things step by step.

**First -** Update POM.xml with correct set of io.cucumber dependencies. We are considering v4.2.6 for this implementation

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

**Point To Note Down -** There could be an issue like everything is ok but still tests do not execute in parallel and could be if your pom.xml is having direct/transitive dependency of testng. As testNG causes Surefire to ignore JUnit wrapper class. If you had testng dependency so remove the TestNG dependency or you can take a call to 2 define 2 execution - For TestNG & JUnit and disable one as per your need.

**Second -** Customize Runner class as per your framework need

```
package com.jacksparrow.automation.suite.runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:features/functional/",
                     glue = {"com.jacksparrow.automation.steps_definitions.functional" },
                   plugin = { "pretty","json:target/cucumber-json/cucumber.json",
                            "junit:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.xml", "html:target/cucumber-reports"},
                   tags = { "@BAMS_Submitted_State_Guest_User" },
                   junit ={ "--step-notifications"},
                   strict = false,
                   dryRun = false,
               monochrome = true)

public class RunCukeTest {
}
```

**Third -** Implementing maven surefire plugin which would actually run tests in parallel

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
        <parallel>methods</parallel>
        <threadCount>2</threadCount>
        <reuserForks>false</reuserForks>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*RunCukeTest.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Fourth -** Implement Hooks.java

```
import cucumber.api.Scenario;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.After;

public class Hooks {

    @Before
    public void setUpScenario(String browser){
        //BaseSteps.getInstance().getBrowserInstantiation(browser); your browser setup method
    }
    @After
    public void afterScenario(Scenario scenario){
    // more code goes here  
    }
   }
```

Comment: with this configuration my test run in 1 thread, dont apply and separate features or scenaries in threads. I run with this configuration mvn clean install.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of cucumber-java you are using? if it is cucumber 4, then you can use threads = "2" (more than 1 thread) to execute scenarios in parallel.

Comment: I have add this tags in cucumber option and run the test with mvn clean test?¿?

Comment: yes.U need to use the Main class contained in the cucumber.api.cli package if u want to use the 'threads' option. The command would be something like - Main.main(new String[]{ “–threads”, “4”, “-g”, “stepdef”, “src/test/resources/features/parallel/”});. No runner is required. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54660808/cucumber-testng-4-0-parallel-execution-defaults-to-10-always